# I don't know if the sentence 'Is it ok if I give this to you?' is correct

Tags: grammar, word-usage, expressions

My friend asked me to download the song "What can I do."
So I did. I didn't get the studio album version, but the "live" version.

I asked him:

> "Is it ok if I give the music for the live version to you?"

Is this sentence correct?

I don't know well..

Comment: I've tried to edit a bit, but was unsure what you ment by 'What can I do' part. Did your friend ask you to do what you can?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence in the title of your question,

> Is it okay if I give this to you?

is correct. Notice, though, that I changed "ok" to "okay," because for now that is still the standard way to spell the word, except you may also write OK (all caps). That is, it's either [*okay* or *OK*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/ok#OK), not *ok*.

As far as the specific sentence,

> "Is it okay if I give the music for the live version to you?"

you originally wrote "music" in the first sentence of your question, and then someone changed it to "piece of music" (which seems odd). So I have changed it to "song", because there are several songs called "What can I do?", but no albums as far as I can see. So, "song" seems the correct and most natural thing to say.

Thus, if we are talking about a song:

> "Is it okay if I give the music for the live version to you?"

Is not quite natural.

It is more natural to say:

> "Is it okay if I give the live version (of the song) to you?"

Comment: Right. And perhaps even more natural to say  "Is it okay if I give you the live version?"